# How do I detect if the Facebook Send Dialog is available?

Tags: facebook, mobile-website, fbjs

The [send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) is a useful piece of functionality.
Sadly it is [not available on mobile devices](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/483239768359255)

I call the api in the following way;

```
app.sendMessage = function(){
  FB.ui({
    app_id: app.facebook_app_id,
    method: "send",
    link:   "http://google.com"
  });
};
```

Right now the outcome on a mobile device is a nasty error page.

Is there a way to detect in javascript whether or not the send dialog is available?

I'd suggest something like;

```
function sendDialogAvailable(){
  return FB.supports("senddialog");
}
```

I could then change my app's functionality according to this property, but right now I fear I'll have to resort to browser sniffing.